QGIS Create a line from points using a range criteria
I am using QGIS to track progress along a track.  I have the track defined in 1 metre intervals in a CSV file X, Y, Distance, in a layout as follows.
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
2, 1, 3
3, 1, 4
3, 0, 5
...

I would like to be able to draw a long only from the Points where Distance <=4, for example.
I can import the points as a CSV and generate a path from the points, but when I do that, the distance information appears to be lost, and I do not have a way to specify the criteria for limiting the drawing of the path.
How can I solve this?

You can try to explode your line into segments using Explode lines tool: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines

The line creation should restart/break when the distance between two rows > 4? So for the points in your example one line should be created?

You just need to Filter your points layer after the CSV import and before generating Points to Path (right-click on the layer & choose 'Filter')
For sake of clarity I duplicated the Points layer before filtering to show the 5 initial points and the 4 filtered ones, but you don't need to.
Field 1 & 2 are the X/Y coordinates and Field 3 is the distance as you have defined it.


